# remote: FATAL: bad username '@'

Tags: git

While pushing the commit from local to git server , got the below mentioned response

```
  git.exe push --all --progress  "origin"

    Counting objects: 7, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 362 bytes, done.
    Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

`remote: FATAL: bad username '@'`

```
    To git@10.237.218.244:gitolite-admin.git
    51174b6..3646648  master -> master

    Success (7488 ms @ 3/18/2014 6:33:59 PM)
```

How to fix this issue

Comment: You can check your current username via "git config user.name"

Answer (score 1):

You must set your username.

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```